# Display a message from internet explorer 10 in Windows 7

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, activex, internet-explorer-10, browser-plugin

I have a web application which needs to call a simple popup message with some text in windows (7 - for arguments sake) In this case I have access to all the users machines who will be running the web app. Is it possible to do this in windows explorer IE10? Would a browser plugin have this capability?

Popup cannot be in-browser, must be a windows activated message

Comment: Please explain specifically why `alert('my message');` isn't doing what you want? What do you mean when you say *windows activated message*?

Comment: I mean I need the alert to appear in "windows 7", Javascript Alert would only show in a browser window.

Comment: "`Alert would only show in a browser window`"?! In IE10 `alert()` is a self-dependent _modal window_, it has even its own icon in the taskbar, and it is shown, despite of the size of the browser window. Can you describe the situation where and how you need this message box, if `alert()` is not suitable.

Comment: Just tried <script>setTimeout("alert('test')",10000);</script> IE10, windows 7 and minimise browser. I only get the pop message if I don't touch anything - and there's no indication that a message has come up in the taskbar - Think this because if I'm not clicking on any other windows the message will get focus. Is there no way I can get the message to display always-on-top? Assume this would require a bit of .net programming but I don't know if the browser can talk to windows or whether this is acheivable via activeX?

Comment: Yes, you could build an ActiveX control for this, but if you go this route, you should use C/C++ instead of .NET. Avoid writing IE extensions and ActiveX controls in .NET.